# JQUERY Smooth Scrolling Large Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We're building a one page website and something we have always had problems with is when the one page site has lots of images. The scroll seems very jittery especially on chrome and we want to look at a much better way of getting it done. Any suggestions of libraries of techniques to use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at lazy loading images? Essentially, you'd only load images once they're about to become visible when scrolling. Also, hiding images once they've scrolled past the view might also help, but I'm not 100% sure on this...

Comment: How well are you images being optimized? Also, are you serving them at full scale or are they sized appropriately? I think the major thing will be reducing the payload as much as possible so your hardware can keep up with rendering. Also, just a stab in the dark, but maybe you could apply translate3d(0,0,0) to the image CSS to force the browser to force hardware acceleration.

Comment: @thykka he's not talking about loading, he's referring to when the images are loaded and rendered, the page still feels laggy because scrolling jumps around. It's caused likely caused because of using large images and then resizing them with CSS. This adds a lot of steps the browser needs to take when re-rendering the page (which happens every time you scroll or resize) and therefore looks like a slow website.

Answer (score 1):

Since each image is likely getting resized with CSS, then with lots of images, the browser has to resize the image when you scroll, which adds a lot of computation.

This will add to the loading/rendering time initially, but should help with laggy scrolling.

```
$('.body').find('.img').each(function() {
    var img = this;
    setTimeout(function() { //use setTimeout so as to not totally block the thread.
        renderImageAsRightSize(img);
    }, 0);
});
//remove loader image.
$(".site-loader").delay(100).fadeOut("slow");

function renderImageAsRightSize (imageObject)
{    
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

   canvas.height = canvas.width * (imageObject.height / imageObject.width);

   var oc   = document.createElement('canvas'),
       octx = oc.getContext('2d');

   oc.width = imageObject.width;
   oc.height = imageObject.height;
   octx.drawImage(imageObject, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);

   octx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);

   //resize final image
   ctx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Essentialliy, converting full-size images being resized with CSS, to the appropriate size (whatever the size of the resized image is on the page) using the canvas.